# GWT App engine Error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I have a small problem with my `GWT` application.

Here's the console output :

```
SEVERE: Received exception processing /Users/je/Documents/HelloWorld/ConnectrStage1/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element.
See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests for more information.
You probably want to enable concurrent requests.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:360)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
   [ERROR] Unable to start App Engine server
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element.
See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests for more information.
You probably want to enable concurrent requests.
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:79)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:360)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:148)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Unable to start embedded HTTP server
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:102)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartupServer method
```

Comment: Okay, please take first a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's pretty clear

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element.
```

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig?hl=fr#Using_Concurrent_Requestsfor more information.